# What is the meaning of 变现？

Tags: meaning

I have this sentence, but I'm not sure what '变现‘ means. I think it's 'assets', but baidu has 'realize' and 'liqidate'. Is '变现‘ an abbreviation for a longer phrase?

三是租赁行业，利用虚假身份证明，骗取汽车租赁公司汽车进行倒卖变现;

三是租赁行业，
The third kind is the rental car industry,

利用虚假身份证明
(they) use fake IDs,

骗取汽车租赁公司
(to) cheat rent-a-car companies

汽车进行倒卖变现;
car carry out resell at profit, realize cash/profit

they then sell the car to get cash.

Comment: Honestly, go download Pleco, and purchase all the add-ons. ABC: covert to cash (V.O.)/appear by magic (V) PLC: convert assets into cash OXC: liquidate, realize KEY: turn into cash/realize (the cash value of assets, stock, etc.) and even 规范: 把非现金的财产、有价证券等换成现金。if you like German: realisieren (V)/realisiert

Comment: 倒卖 is not resell, or at least its missing an important connotation.  If I've gotten it right, it means to sell something that doesn't belong to you. Don't use it for ordinary resellers, who are 經銷商, not 倒賣商. This meaning is not in Google translate.

Answer (score 3):

变现 is a word by itself, not abbreviation, but it literally means 变成现金 (convert (assets) into cash), usually for the purpose of liquidation or realization, so commonly translated into 'liquidate' or 'realize'. The translation for the sentence in your question is correct.